# Selecting chart series collection in vba

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm trying to get a referenced data to plot on my chart. For now, I got the code:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("PyramidPlanned").Activate
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='HC Planned'!$D$2"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='HC Planned'!$D$461:$D$469"
```

I wish I could use a variable where "D" is written. How could I do that?

Txs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As follows:

```
Dim letter As String
letter = "D"

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("PyramidPlanned").Activate
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='HC Planned'!$" & letter & "$2"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='HC Planned'!$" & letter & "$461:$" & letter & "$469"
```